# simple moving average related to a mean

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Am I right in this statement?

Given a series of numeric values that represent measurements (y) over time (x), the closer a simple moving average is to the mean the less volatility in (y) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, no. Consider the sequence

$$
-1, 1, -1, t_0 = 1, t_1 = -1, 1, ...
$$
in which you compute a moving average over an interval of size 2, such as $(-1, 1]$. The moving average function will be constantly 0. Since you can multiply the original sequence by any number $K$, you can make the sequence arbitrarily volatile and still have a moving average that's constant.

If you make that claim for moving averages of every possible size, it's true, in the sense that when the moving-average window is smaller than the sampling interval, the moving averages actually replicate the values (along with a lot of zeroes, perhaps, depending on the sampling frequency of the moving averages).

Answer (score 1):

One can measure a signal $y$ (for example the temperature; or the price of a stock at the stock market) discretely as a function of time $t$, with a fixed sampling period $\delta t$. This way one obtains a set of $N$ measured values $y(n)$, $n= 1,2, 3,... N$.

These measured values will exhibit behaviour at different time scales. For example the outside temperature will typically have a 24 hour periodicity. On the scale of months one will observe the effect of the seasons on the temperature. There will also be a behaviour at much shorter time scales, e.g. at the level of hours, minutes or seconds.

If one is only interested in the behaviour at longer time scales (say a day or more), then the effects at much short time scales can be considered **noise**. [In fact the observed short time scale effects may well be indistinguishable from "real noise", such as measurement errors and rounding effects.]

It is obviously desirable to get rid of this noise. Therefore it is customary to smooth the measured values by means of a moving average window. Essentially this comes down to a discrete version of Gaussian filtering. For example one may use the following 7-term Gaussian filter $(1, 9, 45, 70, 45, 9, 1)$. Note that the sum of the seven terms is $180$, that the window is bell-shaped, and that the width (variance) of the window equals $1$.

Application of the filter will substantially reduce noise at time scales of the order of the width of the window, while leaving the long time behaviour nearly intact. Now the original signal deviated from the long term mean value due to fluctuations at both long times and short times. The volatility results from sum of the variances. After filtering, the short time variance has been considerably reduced. Thus the smoothed signals will exhibit a lower volatility. However the smoothed signal will not be closer to the long term mean than the original signal.